# What's the reason for using an in-memory data store?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm going through the Apress book Pro Core Data and it says the following:

> ...local caching of remote data can benefit from in-memory persistent
>   stores.

I fail to see how caching the data in an in-memory persistent store is any more useful than simply having your app's root view controller hang on to the data. Can someone elaborate more fully on the kinds of situations where an in-memory persistent store might be useful?

Comment: Are you saying that if you need to query this data, it will be easier/faster to do so if it's cached in an in-memory store as opposed to properties of the root view controller?

Comment: No, I am saying that data that is completely unserialized and attached to a view controller is less flexible in terms of how you can query certain parts of it using criteria. You would have to build the logic for that yourself as opposed to CoreData providing it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question indicates a misunderstanding of MVC. You've asked "why would it be faster for the *model* to cache data rather than a *controller*." Controller don't hold data at all, so it doesn't matter how fast it would or wouldn't be. The model holds data. And in a Core Data app, the model is tied to a persistent store.

The fact that persistent stores can be in memory makes coding extremely convenient, since callers don't have to worry about how the data is stored. In your example, callers would need to behave differently (deal with different classes) for data stored in a local store versus a remote store. Core Data abstracts that away, making it easy to move your store wherever you want it.

Answer (score 3):

The benefit of using Core Data with an in-memory store, as compared to simply rolling out your own non-Core Data class hierarchy, is that you benefit from all the other features of Core Data that are not related to persisting data.  These include tracking and undo support, relationship maintenance and change propagation, automatic validation, integration with standard UI components (e.g. NSFetchedResultsController), KVC/KVO, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I was clearly just thinking about some static storing of data, as opposed to what I might want to do with that data.

Answer (score 0):

> ...local caching of remote data

The key work here is remote data, so you may not want to keep that data around between application launches.  In this case an in-Memory store make sense.